# Unable to connect with internet when using Wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, 17.04

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 and connect Internet from WiFi hotspot using my android mobile. It successfully connected and get ip address but Internet is not working. When I ping Google, it shows output as

> ping: google.com: Name or service not known

while the connection information showing 1 to 72 MBPS speed. I also found another question with same issue but got no benefit.

- internet is working if i connect it with usb cable or LAN etc.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/909214/665251 See if it works for you! and do you have 8.8.8.8 added in DNS settings?

Comment: I check it but it is not working. Actually, I think that this is not a problem of DNS because internet is working properly when i connect with USB cable or LAN. It is not working only in wifi connection.

Comment: yes, i missed that what does `lshw -C network` says?

Comment: Thanks @SumeetDeshmukh , the article shared by you, helps me and I am posting answer below which works for me.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and run:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

At the bottom of this file, copy and paste the following:

```
[device] 
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

after pasting it press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>X</kbd> and then type Y to Save it and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can double check if the changes got saved by running the first command again and check if the edited line is there

Now you need to start your network manager for changes to take effect

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

And WiFi should work again, Try to connect it

reference: [Belkin F7D1101 v1 works under Ubuntu 16.10 but not under Lubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909133/belkin-f7d1101-v1-works-under-ubuntu-16-10-but-not-under-lubuntu-17-04/909214#909214)