# Belkin F7D1101 v1 works under Ubuntu 16.10 but not under Lubuntu 17.04

Tags: lubuntu, 17.04

I installed Lubuntu 17.04 on my Computer because its a lot faster with my PC.

i tested before Ubuntu 16.10 and there my Wireless Adaptor "Belkin F7D1101 v1"
works just fine.

Now in Lubuntu I cant find the Adaptor, I have no network.

I don't find a working link for a driver package on the internet.

Can you help me ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/907771/665251 see if this works for you, 17.04 has a little bug with internet wireless connectivity right now

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I need a offline method. i have no internet access on lubuntu. i cant installed gedit.

Comment: Did it work? if not then update your question!

Comment: @OKSI - Use `nano` or `vi` instead.  Like this: `$ nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.  Once you've made your changed, press `ctrl`+`x` then `y`, `enter`.  This will save your changes.

Answer (score 3):

#### This was Originally posted by [Mike_IronFist](https://askubuntu.com/users/68016/mike-ironfist) over [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/905019/665251)

All you need to do is Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and run:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

At the bottom of this file, copy and paste the following:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

after pasting it press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>X</kbd> and then type `Y` to Save it and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

*You can double check if the changes got saved by running the first command again and check if the edited line is there*

Now you need to start your network manager for changes to take effect

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

And WiFi should work again, Try to connect it